# Proper mitigation for category 2 water damage?

Tags: leak, water-damage

I had new flooring installed. The contractor didn't hook up the washing machine drain line so it all got flooded the next day after a load of laundry. They came back to set up several fans and a dehumidifier, but I am given to understand that drain water from a washing machine is category 2 waste and might need more effort than that.

The flooring was cork-backed LVP with foam underlayment on concrete subfloor (for the entire floor). Water went under laundry room walls, up drywall, into subfloor. All flooring in the laundry room was removed, as well as some flooring in the adjacent bathroom and playroom, hallway, and storage room across the hall. Drywall up to about 12" from the floor was removed in the laundry room.

The load of laundry in question was a pile of already dirty t-shirts that our senior cat peed on. In the grand scheme of biohazards and whatnot, this is no big deal. The reason terminology like "category 2" is in the picture is possibly just over-googling. Remediation companies include water from a washing machine's drain line as category 2 damage, in contrast to leakage from a supply line which would be category 1 (effectively clean water).

A couple links, just showing that I didn't come up with this on my own:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_damage
- https://www.jondon.com/how-to/technical-tips/restoration-disaster-recovery/flood-recovery/remediating-drying-category-2-water-losses.html
- https://restoration1.com/blog/the-3-water-damage-categories-and-their-differences/
- https://www.fprestoration.com/blog/2019/august/understanding-the-3-types-of-water-damage/

My concerns about the cleanup process involving -only- drying with no cleaning or decontamination were largely based on sources like the above, and on the amount of water involved -- since the drain hose was flat-out disconnected, this was an entire washing cycle dumped on the floor.

Can anyone advise on what cleaning process they ought to be following for cat 2? I'm halfway to just purchasing a digital copy of the IICRC standards but figured I'd ask around first.

Comment: I guess I don't address these things in terms of "category". It's mildly dirty water, which isn't that different from _not_ dirty water in terms of cleanup. Is there something about the particular discharge that's concerning, such as a biohazard?

Comment: Unless you're washing something dangerous, why would you think there'd be something dangerous in the wash water?

Answer (score 0):

If its vinyl,pull it back on the edges and run fans between floor and vinyl to dry. Cheap wood laminate will be ruined, hardwood can be saved if dried right away with de humidifier as well as fans.